# show current login user's case record only

Tags: soql, case, owner

in below query it'll throw an exception  **unknown token )** 
what the issue for this     *OwnerId= :UserInfo.getUserID()*

```
  SELECT  Status, Origin from Case WHERE OwnerId= :UserInfo.getUserID() And Status != '\open\'';
```

Comment: In case if that is dynamic soql -- apex statements are not executed. Please, execute UserInfo.getUserId() before, assign to variable and insert it in body of SOQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use bind variable in SOQL.

```
String str = 'open';

List<Case> caseList = [SELECT  Status, Origin from Case 
WHERE OwnerId=:UserInfo.getUserID() 
And Status !=:str];
```

For dynamic query use like this:

```
String str = 'open';
String userId = UserInfo.getUserID();
String queryStr = 'SELECT  Status, Origin from Case WHERE OwnerId=:userId And Status !=:str';
List<Case> caseList = Database.query(queryStr);
```